# To what subset can the nine-intersection topological relationship be minimized to

Tags: general-topology

```
 ∘∩∘      ∘∩     ∘∩– 
∩∘       ∩      ∩– 
−∩∘      −∩     −∩−
```

where
 ∘ denotes interior

boundary

−is  exterior

What is the minimum subset of this ?
I currently have 7 but have been told the answer is 4

{∘∩∘ ,∘∩, ∩∘, ∩, ∩–,−∩,−∩− }

Comment: Can you please provide more of an explanation? Are you trying to construct a chain of inclusions of all these sets?

Comment: This isn't rendering correctly at all. Please use Mathjax.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the task is. If you have
\begin{align}
C_1:=\overset{\circ}{A}\cap \overset{\circ}{B}  \hspace{1cm}
C_2:=\partial A\cap \overset{\circ}{B}  \hspace{1cm}
C_3:=\overline{A}\cap \overset{\circ}{B}\\
C_4:=\overset{\circ}{A}\cap \partial{B}  \hspace{1cm}
C_5:=\partial{A}\cap \partial{B}  \hspace{1cm}
C_6:=\overline{A}\cap \partial{B}\\
C_7:=\overset{\circ}{A}\cap \overline{B}  \hspace{1cm}
C_8:=\partial{A}\cap \overline{B}  \hspace{1cm}
C_9:=\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}
\end{align}
and you need the smallest subset of $D\subset\{C_1,\ldots,C_9\}=:C$ such that each element in $C$ can be writen as a combination of elements in $D$ using $\cap$, $\cup$ and $\setminus$, then $D=\{C_1,C_6,C_8\}$ is one possible answer since
$$
C_9=C_1\cup C_6\cup C_8\\
C_5=C_6\cap C_8\\
C_2=C_8\setminus C_5=C_8\setminus (C_6\cap C_8)\\
C_4=C_6\setminus C_5=C_6\setminus (C_6\cap C_8)\\
C_3=C_1\cup C_2=C_1\cup C_8\setminus (C_6\cap C_8)\\
C_7=C_1\cup C_4=C_1\cup C_6\setminus (C_6\cap C_8)
$$